# How to base-64 encode the md5 sum of a string?

Tags: python-3.x

I wish to convert a string to md5 and to base64. Here's what I achieved so far:

```
base64.urlsafe_b64encode("text..." + Var1 + "text..." + 
    hashlib.md5(Var2).hexdigest() + "text...")
```

Python raises a TypeError which says: `Unicode objects must be encoded before hashing`.

Edit: This is what I have now:

```
var1 = "hello"
var2 = "world"
b1 = var1.encode('utf-8')
b2 = var2.encode('utf-8')

result = "text" + 
    base64.urlsafe_b64encode("text" + b1 + "text" +
    hashlib.md5(b2).hexdigest() + "text") + 
    "text"
```

Comment: You may want to change this question's wording to `Convert string to Base64 and MD5 it`. I think that it may be backwards.

Comment: Also, you might find Dive Into Python 3's [chapter on strings](http://diveintopython3.org/strings.html) to be a helpful reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Var1` and `Var2` are strings (unicode) but the `md5()` and `urlsafe_b64encode()` functions require plain old bytes as input.

You must convert `Var1` and `Var2` to a sequence of bytes.  To do this, you need to tell Python how to encode the string as a sequence of bytes.  To encode them as UTF-8, you could do this:

```
b1 = Var1.encode('utf-8')
b2 = Var2.encode('utf-8')
```

You could then pass these byte-strings to the functions:

```
bmd5 = hashlib.md5(b2).digest()  # get bytes instead of a string output
b3 = "text...".encode('utf-8')   # need to encode these as bytes too
base64.urlsafe_b64encode(b3 + b1 ...)
```

Comment: I invoked the function bytes() on Var1 and Var2 but it didn't help. Gave a TypeError: `String argument without an encoding`.
Edit: Now, when using the method encode(), I get the error: `Can't convert 'bytes' object to str implicitly`

Comment: If you want to use `bytes()`, you'll need to specify how the string is to be encoded.  For example: `b1 = bytes(Var1, 'utf-8')` or `b1 = bytes(Var2, 'ascii')`.

Comment: I've updated the answer - the input to `urlsafe_b64encode()` needs to be bytes, so you have to convert the `"text..."` strings to bytes as well.  Also, use the `digest()` method vice `hexdigest()` method to get the md5 sum as bytes.